# How to properly update git subtree

Tags: git, git-subtree

Let's say I have a repositiory Repo and now I want to add folder Common which is separate repository. So the structure should be as following:

```
Repo
    myfile.txt
    Common
        anotherfile.txt
```

As I know there are at least 2 ways to do that: *subtrees* and *submodules*. After reading some git tutorials and manuals I came to the conclusion that *subtree* is what I want.

Ok, so I've added the folder to my repo:

```
git subtree add --prefix Common https://github.com/my/Common.git master --squash
```

Ok, now it looks as expected. After some time I want to update the subtree folder. But unfortunately the only way I've found so far is:

```
git subtree pull --prefix Common https://github.com/my/Vommon.git master --squash
```

Why should I again enter the repository Url? Isn't that stored somewhere in the git structure? What if I have several subtrees? I don't think that someone remember all the urls.

Is there a way to do that in some simple way? Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Does git pull -s subtree not work?

Comment: @MFnx `git pull --strategy subtree` and `git subtree pull` are 2 completely different and independent things.

Answer (score 0):

> Why should I again enter the repository Url? Isn't that stored somewhere in the git structure?

Nop. The URL is stored with submodules but not with subtrees. A subtree is fully integrated into the repository, it doesn't remember it's a separate subtree, it doesn't remember where it came from.

> What if I have several subtrees?

Create git aliases or shell aliases or scripts to pull/push many subtrees.

Or switch back to submodules. They have many disadvantages but at least they remember from where they were cloned.